# Windows Phone 7 Slider Accent Both Foreground and Background Colors

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors, slider, background-foreground

I need to create a slider with two colors, so that when you slide one direction or the other it appears as though one color has a higher percent over the other, or vice versa. However, when I apply the code below, wp7 automatically dims the background color, so it's not the proper color. The slider is in a list box which iterates over objects, so the colors are constantly changing. Any way to make the color of the foreground match the color of the background? (so that #ffffff would appear white on both sides of the slider, and not white on one and a gray on the other?)

Code is below.

```
                <Slider
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Background="{Binding AwayTeam.Color}"
                    Foreground="{Binding HomeTeam.Color}"
                    FlowDirection=""
                    Value="4.7"
                    />
```

Ok, so I'm adding some clarification. Look at the picture at this link. [Slider Example](http://www.ro-connect.com/images/sliderExample.png)

The bottom background (right hand side) is what I need the slider to look like, and that blue is what the color is supposed to look like. But, when I set that blue as the background color, wp7 makes it darker. The top slider is what wp7 currently does to the background color, and the bottom is what I need the background color to look like.

Comment: I want to try to help you but I'm not sure what exactly you want to do. What's the slider supposed to do?

Comment: I agree - I read your first few sentences, fired up Expression blend, read the rest, closed blend. Can you explian further 'any way to make the color of the foreground match the color of the background? (so that #ffffff would appear white on both sides of the slider, and not white on one and gray on the other?)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a minor modification to the sliders template:

1. Open the project in Expression Blend.
2. Select the slider in the "Objects and Timeline" window.
3. Right click on it and select: Edit Template > Edit a copy
4. In the xaml for the template, find this line

   ```
   <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrack" Grid.Column="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          Height="12" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,22,0,50" Opacity="0.2"/>
   ```
5. remove `Opacity="0.2"`
6. Accept this answer. :)